# Leaving the Schengen Area for Two Months on Jeune Fille Au Pair Visa?

Tags: visa, france, schengen

I am a US citizen in Paris on my second year as an au pair (VLS-TS).  I have already renewed my visa, received the récépissé (valid until Jan 25), and my carte de séjour is ready for pickup (just can’t get an appointment, already contacted prefecture about this).I would be returning at the beginning of Jan at the latest.

Now here’s the problem: I am changing host families and it looks like I may have to return to the US for a time, around two months. What can/should I do? How much time do I have?